# iOS 8+ - UITextView Not Stretching Vertically in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, autolayout, uitextview

I am using Auto Layout and have a `UITextView` in a `UITableViewCell`. The `UITableViewCell`'s height is calculated automatically based on the constraints. Here is how I am specifying that the cell should be self-sizing:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    ...

    // Set the estimated row height
    self.myTableView.estimatedRowHeight = self.myTableView.rowHeight

    // Set the height of the cell row based on its constraints
    self.myTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    // Prevent extra rows from displaying
    self.myTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

    ...
}
```

I am certain that all of the constraints (leading, trailing, top, and bottom) are set properly on all of the UI elements on my `UITableViewCell`, but for some reason the `UITextView` is not stretching to fit its available text. I've tried reloading the layout and the constraints in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and the `willDisplayCell` methods to no avail.

If I scroll down on the table and then scroll back up to a given cell, the UITextView DOES indeed stretch properly. But upon first load of the view, it is not acceptable for some of the text to be cut off.

I've tried just about everything I can think of, and I cannot get the `UITextView` to stretch. Even stranger, I made a test app, the `UITextView` did stretch properly. It's not working on my app for some reason, though.

I'm pretty stuck and could use some help. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that my `UITableViewCell` had a `Disclosure Indicator` accessory. All I had to do was remove the accessory (set to `None`), and everything is working great! I'm not sure why this works, but it seems like it's a bug. Self-sizing cells should work regardless of whether or not there is an accessory on the cell.

### **Note**

This bug appears to have been fixed in iOS 9+. For apps that need to support iOS 8, I would recommend removing the accessory from your `UITableViewCell` and replacing the accessory with a custom image.